# WebDriverWait is throwing exception before time span specified at the time of object initialization

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium WebDriverWait object to dynamically control the timeout for object detection in my code. But this object is timing out before the timespan specified in WebDriverWait object is spent. For ex. I have object initialized with 10 seconds timeout time span but object is timing out in  around 2 seconds.

Here is my code

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
try
{
  wait.Until(drv => (drv.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='TopTitle']"))));   //drv.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='TopTitle']")) throws exception
}
catch
{
  //exception handlers
}
```

I am running it in debug mode and i can clearly see `drv.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='TopTitle']"))` within 2-3 seconds

Exception and stack trace:

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@class='TopTitle']"}
>   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
>   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary parameters)
>   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
>   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByXPath(String xpath)
>   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_c(ISearchContext context)
>   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
>   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
>   at VS_UnitTest.Navigation.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0(IWebDriver drv) in c:\Git\WebadminTests\WebAdminTests\Navigation.cs:line 511
>   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait.Until[TResult](Func condition)

Comment: If you run it locally you are going to see the exceptions regardless - Visual Studio is set, by default, to catch & show you most exceptions.

Comment: This didn't throw any exception before today. And i am still testing the same UI i was testing for months. Now it is throwing exception even on home page, where element is clearly present. But drv.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='TopTitle']"))) throws Unable to find element exception

Comment: Then you've got an entirely different issue not related to the WebDriverWait at all. What's changed? What browser is this in? What version of Selenium? Have you upgraded that recently? If not, then you can be sure it *isn't* Selenium at fault if your backing library hasn't been changed. **Show us the full error & stack trace**.

Comment: Absolutely nothing has changed. used to work till now.

Comment: So what browser is this in? Where's the error and stack trace?

Comment: I have added exception and stack trace in question details

Comment: What browser are you using? We need all the details you can give.

Comment: sorry,
it is firefox browser version 24.0
and also one more thing, this happens only when i debug code.
I just ran it normally (without debug) and all tests passed.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriverWait only handles certain kinds of exceptions.  You need to handle the other kinds yourself by using the   FluentWait.ignoring  feature  (WebDriverWait is an extension of FluentWait).  If you look at the source code, it appears that WebDriverWait only ignores NotFoundException.class  on its own.   To ignore [other exceptions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html), you need to add a catch class (or a generic catch clause).  NOTE: In the case of TimeoutException... do not use that in the ignoring clause and instead wrap WebDriverWait in a try-catch and catch the TimeoutException outside of the wait.

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@class='TopTitle']"} is the exception i get on wait.until line
 and Timed out after 10 seconds exception on catch line
This code used to work till now. Today it started throwing this exception

Comment: I was I was better with the C# syntax.  I'm a Java developer and so I can't see anything obvious that you are doing wrong.  But, if I were to guess, I think the problem is that you set the WebDriverWait to 10 seconds but the .findElement call has a 30-second default timeout, which is larger.

Comment: i will give it a try by increasing wait timeout to 35 seconds.

Comment: You can also change the findElement timeout with this:  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);